# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route on app.js

```
<Route exact path = "/:name" component = {CityPage} />
```

And I have a component inside of CityPage I have a component

```
render(){
    return(
            <CityHome />
    )
}
```

And in that component I have

```
<p> {this.props.match.params.name} </p>
```

but when I run the program it shows the error

Why?

Comment: You need to provide more code if you want help. It just means that `this.props.match` is `undefined`...

Comment: The whole Cityhome class code would help, there should be a property match, with a value

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're passing any props to `CityHome`. That would explain why it's `undefined` (assuming that's the component you're accessing from). It might be as simple as `<CityHome match={this.props.match} />` but with limited code provided I can't say for sure.

Comment: @BrianThompson but if I create another component and i want that props aswell

Answer (score 0):

React Router doesn't pass any props to the component by default. If you need to access that data, you should use the `render` prop instead of `component` when defining your `Route`:

```
<Route exact path="/:name" render={routeProps => (
  <CityPage match={routeProps.match} />
)} />
```

As you can see here, `render` is a method that receives the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) and returns a view. You can use that function to pass down any of these values to the components you add to the returned view.